# How can I pull only the price text from this html in bs4 python?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

So i'm building a web scraper and am having trouble pulling only the price from [this page](https://www.carsforsale.com/Search?SearchTypeID=2&ZipCode=17403&Radius=25&Conditions=&PageNumber=1&OrderBy=relevance&OrderDirection=desc).
Python is pulling the $550 too. I'm just looking for the $41,991. The html is below.

```html
<div class="snapshot__body-content">
              <div class="snapshot__col1">
               <ul class="snapshot__details list-unstyled">
                <li class="snapshot__details-price">
                 <sup>
                  $
                 </sup>
                 41,991
                 <!-- -->
                 <a class="btn-link snapshot__details-monthly hidden-xs hidden-sm" href="/vehicle/details/73082384">
                  <sup>
                   $
                  </sup>
                  <span>
                   550
                  </span>
                  /mo*
                 </a>
```

And here is my current code for bs4.

```
try:
        data["Price"] = item.find_all("li", {"class":"snapshot__details-price"})[0].text.replace("/mo*","")
    except:
        data["Price"] = None
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using `.contents`

```
for data in soup.select(".snapshot__details-price"):
    # for original html
    print("$" + data.contents[1].strip())

    # for formatted html above
    # print("$" + data.contents[2].strip())
```

Comment: Perfect! Works well with my dataframe too. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can try `get_text()` method to extract inner text of tag  after that `rsplit()` to get the result.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
response = """<div class="snapshot__body-content">
    <div class="snapshot__col1">
        <ul class="snapshot__details list-unstyled">
            <li class="snapshot__details-price">
                <sup>
                  $
                 </sup>
                 41,991
                 
                
                <!-- -->
                <a class="btn-link snapshot__details-monthly hidden-xs hidden-sm" href="/vehicle/details/73082384">
                    <sup>
                   $
                  </sup>
                    <span>
                   550
                  </span>
                  /mo*
                 
                
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(response, 'lxml')

for data in soup.find_all('li',{"class":"snapshot__details-price"}):
    print(data.get_text(strip=True).rsplit('$', maxsplit=1)[0])
```